# Redraw function on dropdown change with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a function `drawMap` that is called once the page loads displaying `data1` info and a drop down.

When the drop down option is selected it updates and changes the argument in the `drawMap` function to update it with the other variable data using `.onchange`

The problem is that when the drop down is changed the data is added to the already called data result in stacking of the data.

How can I prevent the stacking effect and load only the corresponding data when drop down is changed?

```js
// populate drop-down
var dropdown_options = [{
    value: "data1",
    text: "Data 1: Read Hello World"
  },
  {
    value: "data2",
    text: "Data 2: Read Hello Dhivya"
  }
];

var data1 = {
  name: "World",
  date: "7 March 2017",
}

var data2 = {
  name: "Dhivya",
  date: "7 March 2017",
}

var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown");

dropDown.selectAll(".options")
  .data(dropdown_options)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("class", "options")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.text;
  });


function drawMap(info) {
  // console.log(settings);
  // console.log("Variable Data 1", info)
  // Add a SVG with responsive set up
  htmlText = "Hello" + info.name + ", today's date is" + info.date;

  d3.select("#text")
    .append("p")
    .text(htmlText)

}; //draw map



drawMap(data1);
// console.log(dropDown);

dropDown.on("change", function() {
  selected = this.value;
  console.log(selected);
  if (selected == "data2") {
    drawMap(data2);
  }
  if (selected == "data1") {
    drawMap(data1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.thehindu.com/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>


<div id="election-viz">
  <select id="dropdown"></select>
  <div id="text"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your function `drawMap` appends the new data to the page each time it is called. If you want to prevent this you could clear the page first:

```
var text = d3.select("#text");

text.select("p")
    .remove(); // remove the old <p> element

text.append("p")
    .text(htmlText)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution (out of many) is defining the variable outside the update function:

```
var p = d3.select("#text")
    .append("p");
```

And, inside the update function, only changing it:

```
p.text(htmlText);
```

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
// populate drop-down
var dropdown_options = [{
    value: "data1",
    text: "Data 1: Read Hello World"
  },
  {
    value: "data2",
    text: "Data 2: Read Hello Dhivya"
  }
];

var data1 = {
  name: "World",
  date: "7 March 2017",
}

var data2 = {
  name: "Dhivya",
  date: "7 March 2017",
}

var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown");

dropDown.selectAll(".options")
  .data(dropdown_options)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("class", "options")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.text;
  });
  
var p = d3.select("#text")
    .append("p");

function drawMap(info) {
  // console.log(settings);
  // console.log("Variable Data 1", info)
  // Add a SVG with responsive set up
  htmlText = "Hello" + info.name + ", today's date is" + info.date;


    p.text(htmlText)

}; //draw map



drawMap(data1);
// console.log(dropDown);

dropDown.on("change", function() {
  selected = this.value;
  console.log(selected);
  if (selected == "data2") {
    drawMap(data2);
  }
  if (selected == "data1") {
    drawMap(data1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.thehindu.com/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>


<div id="election-viz">
  <select id="dropdown"></select>
  <div id="text"></div>

</div>
```

Of course, a way more elegant solution would be binding data to your selection.

The worst solution, however, is *removing* elements and drawing them again in the update. That's what I call *lazy update*, and it's unnecessary when properly using D3.

Comment: I think _worst_ solution is a bit of a stretch, just of the top of my head I can think of far worse solutions, refreshing the page whenever the selection changes for example.

Comment: Yes, indeed, which is just an exaggerated example of removing something and painting it again.